# Method 405 is not allowed, but in the API routing I defined POST

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

I am creating a SPA with the help of Laravel and Vue and the routing has worked previously, but for some reason it is giving me this error now: "Method 405 is not allowed".

Here is the warning message I am getting:

*"[Deprecation] The website requested a subresource from a network that it could only access because of its users' privileged network position. These requests expose non-public devices and servers to the internet, increasing the risk of a cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack, and/or information leakage. To mitigate these risks, Chrome deprecates requests to non-public subresources when initiated from non-secure contexts, and will start blocking them in Chrome 92 (July 2021). See https://chromestatus.com/feature/5436853517811712 for more details."*

This is the function which makes an API call:

```
axios.post('api/molliepayment', { products, totalPrice }).then(response => {
    window.location.href = response.data.data._links.checkout.href;
}).catch(() => {});
```

Here is the API routes file:

```
Route::post('molliepayment', [OrderController::class, 'preparePayment'])->name('mollie.payment');
```

As last, here is the Vue-Router:

```
{
    path: '/checkout',
    component: Checkout,
    children: [
        {            
            path: '',
            component: Address,
        },
        {
            path: '/checkout/payment',
            component: Payment,
        },                
        {
            path: '/checkout/confirm',
            component: OrderCheck,
        }
    ],
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
    }
},
```

One extra thing to note: I am making use of a SSH tunnel

This is my beforeMount():

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('vue-laravel-ecommerce.jwt')
```

This is my cors.php config:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

**Extra information**
I think it happened after I started using child routes.

Comment: provide the full URL like `localhost:8000/api/molliepayment`

Comment: Ye I missed out on a / ! Such a rooky mistake

Comment: That is programming. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request `axios.post('api/molliepayment'...` refers to a relative URL, meaning that if you are e.g. currently in `/checkout/payment` it would make a request to `http://example.com/checkout/payment/api/molliepayment` if you have a SPA and a "catch-all" route to load the index then this is what will be hit with this request, and presumably POST is not allowed for such a request.

You can use `axios.post('/api/molliepayment'...` to fix this but an even better approach is to pass the actual full URL via your .blade.php view e.g.

```
<script>
window.molliepaymentURL = '{{ route('mollie.payment' }}';
</script>
```

and use `axios.post(window.molliepaymentURL...`

This will allow you to change the route path without needing to change the JS and in addition it will not break if you are using an uncommon host setup where the Laravel root is a sub-path